# Product of two 4 positions without writing the components

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, time, velocity, speed

I was able to solve the first part of the following question by expanding the terms as vectors
[image]
I can't understand how to do it without expanding so I had a look at the answers.
[image]
I understand how we get the numerator of the second equality by using $dx^\alpha=(cdt,d\vec r)$. I don't understand how $d\tau d\tau=(ds/dt)^2$ though. As far as I know the definition of proper time is $d\tau=dt/\gamma=ds/c$. My friends said that the $dt$ in the numerator should be a $c$ and I agree. Just here to confirm that we haven't missed anything.

(the second part is no issue)

Thank you.

Comment: $ds^2  = \pm c^2 d \tau^2$?

Comment: @Prahar yes that is also what we thought. But in that case the answer $d\tau d\tau=(ds/dt)^2)$ would be wrong.

Comment: Not sure what you are saying. Your equation (in the comments) is nonsensical.